# NoSuchMethodError when running Junit @Test method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration.

I have this Junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class, BasicDataSourceHibernateConfig.class },
                      loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
public class DeviceEventServiceImplTest {


    @Inject
    DeviceEventService deviceEventService;



    @Test
    public void testFindWithActiveAlarm() throws Exception {
        List<DeviceEvent> deviceEvents = getDeviceEventService().findWithActiveAlarm();
        System.out.println(deviceEvents);
    }



    public DeviceEventService getDeviceEventService() {
        return deviceEventService;
    }


    public void setDeviceEventService(DeviceEventService deviceEventService) {
        this.deviceEventService = deviceEventService;
    }
}
```

But this error when I run it:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotationAttributes(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:365)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:274)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:154)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Don't mix jars from different spring versions. Check your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons for java.lang.NoSuchMethodError is multiple versions of incompatible jar files. Check Effective pom file and make sure you just have one which is compatible with your spring/spring boot version. In above case, it would be conflicts of spring-core dependency.

Answer (score 1):

don't need to check your classpath,
yes in the most of the cases, it's caused by the different versions of JARS used.
For me it's related about Spring Boot version,
so below there are steps to debug:

1) Check your txt debug file (normallyl it's in target/surefire-reports)
2) In this debug file, get the package which cause the error (for it was spring boot)
3) then do this command with this package and check all dependencies are in the same version:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep spring-boot
```

4) For me all version of spring boot was 2.1.1.RELEASE except org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar was 1.4

5) Fix the bad version to be equivalent to the others one.

6) run:

```
mvn -U clean package
```

Option -U it forces maven to check all artifacts in remote repository & update local repository, if it's stale.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the "activemq-all" jar has a different version of Spring inside it.
You should change to using a reduced version of the activemq jar instead.